# backup postgresql database to submit with project

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have a final year project written in Matlab in conjunction to a postgresql database called 'hm'.

I asked in which way could I submit the database and I was told to perform a back up of the database using pgadmin3.

What is the recommended format? I want the person to be correcting the assignment to be able to use my own database in his own postgresql version. Which format and options should I check to ensure that they can work with the backup?

I am using postgresql 9.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pg_dump -Fc` and tell them to load it with `pg_restore`.

If you've created user accounts and other global objects you'll want to also provide a `pg_dumpall --globals-only` to them.

Comment: I am a bit of a noob in this area. you do this in SQL Shell (psql) ? I am trying this: $ pg_dump -Fc mydb > db.dump. What should I type when the terminal says: Database(postgres): and Port(5432) ? I tried some inputs but it returns warnings "ignored"

Comment: OS command line shell, not `psql`. `pg_dump` is a utility program. Use the same connection options as you use for `psql`. For details see the PostgreSQL manual.

Comment: i tried to do it in the terminal but always getting command not found. isnt the backup function in pgadmin convenient? doesn't it do the same thing? perhaps you know which options I could choose to get the same result as the pgdump?

Comment: Presumably `pg_dump` isn't on your `PATH`; you might need to invoke it with the full path to where it's installed. Also, yes, there is a PgAdmin backup function. You did not mention that you were using PgAdmin. It's documented in the PgAdmin manual. Right click on the database in PgAdmin and choose "backup".

Comment: thanks managed! from the dump options, what options do you recommend choosing?

Comment: @JurgenCuschieri I don't use PgAdmin, so I can't really say. Use a "custom" format dump (probably default), otherwise shouldn't need anything special.